# splitting unicode string into words

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to split a Unicode string into words (simplistic), like this:

```
print re.findall(r'(?u)\w+', "раз два три")
```

What I expect to see is:

```
['раз','два','три']
```

But what I really get is:

```
['\xd1', '\xd0', '\xd0', '\xd0', '\xd0\xb2\xd0', '\xd1', '\xd1', '\xd0']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

If I use `u` in front of the string:

```
print re.findall(r'(?u)\w+', u"раз два три")
```

I get:

```
[u'\u0440\u0430\u0437', u'\u0434\u0432\u0430', u'\u0442\u0440\u0438']
```

Edit 2:

Aaaaand it seems like I should have read docs first:

```
 print re.findall(r'(?u)\w+', u"раз два три")[0].encode('utf-8')
```

Will give me:

```
раз
```

Just to make sure though, does that sound like a proper way of approaching it?

Comment: There's a difference between pulling out all the `\w+` strings and splitting on `\s+`.  Obviously you want to have `(?u)` enabled in both cases though.  And don't do a manual encode before you print. Print to a character stream, which will have an encoding, not to a byte stream, which won't. Use [Matthew Barnett's regex library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) for Unicode regexes in Python. Don't use `re`: it doesn't work right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're actually getting the stuff you expect in the unicode case. You only think you are not because of the weird escaping due to the fact that you're looking at the *reprs* of the strings, not not printing their unescaped values. (This is just how lists are displayed.)

```
>>> words = [u'\u0440\u0430\u0437', u'\u0434\u0432\u0430', u'\u0442\u0440\u0438'] 
>>> for w in words:
...     print w # This uses the terminal encoding -- _only_ utilize interactively
... 
раз
два
три
>>> u'раз' == u'\u0440\u0430\u0437'
True
```

Don't miss my remark about printing these unicode strings. Normally if you were going to send them to screen, a file, over the wire, etc. you need to manually encode them into the correct encoding. When you use `print`, Python tries to leverage your terminal's encoding, but it can only do that if there is a terminal. Because you don't generally know if there is one, you should only rely on this in the interactive interpreter, and always encode to the right encoding explicitly otherwise.

In this simple splitting-on-whitespace approach, you might not want to use regex at all but simply to use the `unicode.split` method.

```
>>> u"раз два три".split()
[u'\u0440\u0430\u0437', u'\u0434\u0432\u0430', u'\u0442\u0440\u0438']
```

Your top (bytestring) example does not work because `re` basically assumes all bytestrings are ASCII for its semantics, but yours was not. Using unicode strings allows you to get the right semantics for your alphabet and locale. As much as possible, textual data should always be represented using `unicode` rather than `str`.

Comment: No, I do not believe that you should be manually encoding. You should set the encoding on the output stead.  If you use Matthew Barnett's `regex` [replacement library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) for `re`, then a lot of Unicode problems go away. If you use `regex` on a wide build w/Python3, your Unicode tribulations are much improved. Violate any one of those three requirements, and you will suffer; violate more than one, and you will suffer more.

Comment: @tchrist, No, you should always be dealing with encoding and decoding explicitly rather than relying on the implicit encoding like the example does (except for in this one very narrow case of Python 2 interactive `print`). By this I *don't* mean that you should be repeatedly calling `encode` or `decode` in your high-level code.

Comment: Using the file-like objects returned by `codecs.open` in Python 2 and non-`'b'` `open` in Python 3 or any of many other things that encapsulate encoding, like the `json` or `sqlite` modules, would be just as explicit. What I was trying to state (clearly I didn't succeed well) wasn't that you should be calling `str.decode`/`unicode.encode` (Python 3 `bytes.decode`/`str.encode`) personally all the time, but rather that you shouldn't be relying on implicit encoding.